# Express API/ReactJS/HTTPS - blocked:mixed-content on localhost

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, reactjs, https

### Context

I build a web app thanks to node/express and react.
I just put it on my prodcution server (api and web app) I wanted to secure with ssl certificat.

---

### API

I setup the api with (minified version of my code) :

```
const https = require('https');

const port = normalizePort('3000');
app.set('port', port);

app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');

const ssl = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/habitatdurable.pro/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/habitatdurable.pro/fullchain.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/habitatdurable.pro/chain.pem')
}

const server = https.createServer(ssl,app);
```

- First question : How can I test my API with POSTMAN for example ?

---

### WebApp

When I try to use my web app (I got Nginx on top of it to proxy_pass `433` request to `3002`) with https (w/o it's working fine) I got all my ajax request blocked with the error `mixed-content`. I totally understand the meaning of this error but I'm on localhost.

- How can I fixe this ? Do I have to make a secure request even on localhost ?

---

### Next Step

And last request. If in a near futur I want to put my services on 2 differents servers, how to setup my webApp to work on https ?

Thanks.

Comment: https:localhost in that way you can test in your localhost